# Keeps on getting message files are identical using find

Tags: find, rename

Whenever I enter this:

```
find . -type f -name 'diag*' -mtime +30 -exec mv {} temp_diag \;
```

in SunOS I always get this message

```
mv: ./temp_diag/diagnostic.log.68.gz and temp_diag/diagnostic.log.68.gz are identical
mv: ./temp_diag/diagnostic.log.37.gz and temp_diag/diagnostic.log.37.gz are identical
mv: ./temp_diag/diagnostic.log.18.gz and temp_diag/diagnostic.log.18.gz are identical
```

The command I used just works fine but am just concerned with what the messages mean.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When using this command it will go from the current path down.
So you have something like this:

```
dir1
dir1/temp_diag
dir1/temp_diag/file1
```

You are running your commmand from inside `dir1` and find enters into dir1/temp_diag and executes

```
mv ./temp_diag/file1 temp_diag/file1
```

You are actually telling the command to move the file to itself.

**UPDATE:**
If you don't have any subdirs with files then you can add the option to find of maxdepth 1.
So:

```
find . -type f -name 'diag*' -maxdepth 1 -mtime +30 -exec mv {} temp_diag \;
```

or if you have subdirs but don't want to include temp_diag then:

```
find . -path ./temp_diag -prune -o -print -type f -name 'diag*' -mtime +30 -exec mv {} temp_diag\;
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation there's alot that I don't understand about exec, i though it was just straightforward. Is there anyway i can improve this command?

Answer (score 1):

Your `find` command is traversing down into the temp_diag directory, finding a file, and you're then trying to `mv` the file onto itself.

Comment: Thanks for answering eightbittony. Is there anyway you can explain to me what {} actually does? I just assumed whatever result i got from find will be contained within these brackets and moved to another folder but i don't think its the case.